# installing microsoft graph sdk for .net causes system.diagnostic.diagnosticsource error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I get the error after I install the latest Microsoft.Graph Sdk using Nuget. I am running an Asp.Net MVC 4 project with .Net Framework 4.6 version: "Could not load System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource 4.0.2 or one of its dependencies"

I tried installing the System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource package, but no luck. I've tried other solutions including installing System.Net.Http, but still no luck. Uninstalling the graph sdk gets rid of the error.

Comment: What version of System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource do you have in `bin` folder?

Comment: I've installed Microsoft.Graph 3.21.0 and it installed System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource 4.7.1. Try to uninstall Microsoft.Graph, cleand bin folder and uninstall Microsoft.Graph again. What version of System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource do you have in packages.config?   <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.7.1" targetFramework="net461" />

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned my bin folder, I still had the same issue. Finally, using binding redirect fix the problem for me. Added the following to web.config under `<runtime><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">` section:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```